# Using more than one spell on a scroll

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, magic-items

Playing Pathfinder I have come to realize there is minimal literature on putting multiple spells on a single scroll (or just am not looking in the right places). I am stumped on how to do this.

Can I even put two spells on one scroll? If so, do you just add the two spell levels together or create two scrolls and merge them?

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site! Why don't you check out the [tour] to get started? It looks like you've actually got a few questions here, so I would recommend editing your question to focus on just one part for us to answer, then you can ask another question if you need.

Answer (score 13):

## You *can* put multiple spells on the same scroll

Magic Item Creation on [Creating Scrolls](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Creating-Scrolls) on Time Required says

> Scribing a scroll requires 1 day per 1,000 gp of the base price. Although an individual scroll might contain more than one spell, each spell must be scribed as a separate effort, meaning that no more than 1 spell can be scribed in a day.

So, for example, a wizard scribes one scroll of 3 spells in the same amount of time as he makes three scrolls of 1 spell. Further, because each spell's scribed individually, the cost of one 3-spell scroll and three 1-spell scrolls remains identical.

This means that there are equal mechanic reasons *not* to make scrolls of multiple spells (e.g. an opponent may [sunder](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Sunder) a valuable scroll) as there are *to* make scrolls of multiple spells (e.g. a creature can cast spells freely from a valuable scroll after taking but a single move action to retrieve the scroll).

One may struggle to convince the GM that, as [other](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Creating-Scrolls) [answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/65119/8610) mention, a caster can manipulate in the heat of combat, for example, a 20-ft.-long scroll of 20 spells, but this difficulty isn't reflected in the rules. On the other hand, perhaps it needn't be; we are talking about a *magic* scroll, after all.

---

### Followup questions

These questions were originally asked in this answer's Comments.

- **When employing a long scroll is a caster still limited by the spell's casting time, usually to a lone spell per standard action?**

  Yes. Each spell on the scroll is still cast individually. Having the spells share the same medium is for convenience, having no other mechanical effect (much like having a staff that allows the user to employ multiple spells—the spells themselves are still used individually). Casting multiple spells in a lone action is one of the wizard's holy grails, not something accomplished simply by putting the spells on a scroll (or staff).
- **From a scroll a caster *can* cast—both in the same turn—a spell modified by the feat [Quickened Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/quicken-spell-metamagic---final) with a casting time of 1 swift action *and* a spell with a casting time of 1 standard action, right?**

  Yes. The rules permit scribing scrolls of spells modified by metamagic feats (["[Y]ou can store a metamagic version of a spell in a scroll, potion, or wand."](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats)), but the reduced casting time of the modified spell isn't a property of scrolls but of the metamagic feat.
- **Would a house rule permitting casters to use long scrolls to cast simultaneously multiple spells be unbalanced?**

  Yes. Casting spells is already the most efficient use of actions in the game. A GM who allows casters to employ scrolls to generate multiple magical effects simultaneously will find that every character who can takes the feat [Scribe Scroll](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/scribe-scroll-item-creation---final), that casters even more rapidly overshadow other PCs, that standard casting is obsoleted by his house rule, and that even the non-casters will invest heavily in the skill Use Magic Device so they, too, can share in the weird bounty. Even in a one-on-one campaign, the lone PC is doomed when an *opponent* whips out a scroll. (However, in a one-on-one campaign, I can imagine this as a campaign-specific secret technique that the lone PC is allowed to use but others creatures aren't (except, perhaps inevitably, the big bad), but the GM should expect such a character to spend *all* of his downtime scribing or acquiring scrolls.)

Comment: So when these scrolls are then "strapped or rod bound" I can only use one spell per action. Not combining effects of spells?

Comment: Other than the rule books not stating that they combine in effects could the gm and player work a system to allow such spells to occur?

Comment: To use mutiple spells (on a scroll) in a round you could just scribe them as quickened? (obviously at a much increaced level)

Answer (score 6):

There definitely isn't a lot of information regarding multiple spells on one scroll, but it is possible.

According to [Scrolls](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/scrolls)

> A scroll is a spell (or collection of spells) that has been stored in written form

So we definitely can have more then one spell on a scroll.  To create a scroll, you'll first need the [Scribe Scroll](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/scribe-scroll-item-creation---final) feat, which will allow you to create a scroll.

For multiple spells on one scroll, refer to the following with regards to the length:

> A scroll holding more than one spell has the same width (about 8-1/2 inches) but is an extra foot or so long for each additional spell. Scrolls that hold three or more spells are usually fitted with reinforcing rods at each end rather than simple strips of leather.

There doesn't seem to be any restriction on the length of a scroll - Though I hardly imagine reading through a 12 foot scroll in the middle of battle would be very practical.

Comment: If it helps, I think 3.5rd edition said that a spell requires 1 foot of scroll per spell level, meaning that a six-foot scroll could hold six first-level spells, two third-level spells, one second-level and one fourth-level spell, or any other valid combination that added up to six or less.

Comment: The scroll section has additional information that isn't provided here concerning multiple spells on a single scroll.

Comment: @GMJoe where does it say that? A 9ft scroll for a single spell doesn't sound practical, nor does it make much sense that such a long spell would fit in a spellbook...

Comment: @Erik I don't have my DMG on me at the moment, but I'm reasonably certain. Bear in mind, scrolls are usually stored rolled up. Also, spells take one spellbook page per level to store; Perhaps the designer assumed spellbook pages were about a foot long?

Comment: @Erik It seems that Pathfinder's changed scrolls to be substantially shorter, though.

Answer (score 4):

The physical description of a scroll states the following:

> A scroll is a heavy sheet of fine vellum or high-quality paper. An area about 8-1/2 inches wide and 11 inches long is sufficient to hold one spell. The sheet is reinforced at the top and bottom with strips of leather slightly longer than the sheet is wide. **A scroll holding more than one spell has the same width (about 8-1/2 inches) but is an extra foot or so long for each additional spell. Scrolls that hold three or more spells are usually fitted with reinforcing rods at each end rather than simple strips of leather.** A scroll has AC 9, 1 hit point, hardness 0, and a break DC of 8.

Emphasis mine. Meaning that for every additional spell on a scroll, its a foot longer. Scrolls longer than three feet have rods that support either end of the parchment.

The text doesn't specify exactly how long a scroll can be, but I think this is something you could likely discuss with your GM. To scribe a scroll you must have the Scribe scroll feat and have the spell either written in your spellbook or be able to spontaneously cast the spell.