# How many spells can be on a scroll?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

Looking at scroll descriptions I note that scrolls can have multiple spells on them but have been unable to find the information regarding how many can be placed on a single scroll when scribing a scroll. Is there a limit?

Comment: [Question also available in *Pathfinder* flavor.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/65115/8610)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RAW, no. DMG 199, however, says that scrolls are

> an extra foot or so long for each extra spell. Scrolls that hold three or more spells are usually fitted with reinforcing rods.

So I don't think that there is a mechanical restriction, but there seems to be fluff limitations on how long a scroll can physically be.